# echo writes successfully on 8 bytes input but failed for others

Tags: php, html, linux, shell, web-applications

Thought a lot but could not find a suitable title ... so also suggest on title.

Also I am not showing HTML code to avoid making post larger. With PHP variables names and part of figure shown, its easy to understand the situation.

Actual problem is described here -

Here is a code snippet which is just a small part of a large code. The confusion is b/w two situations. Both are mentioned below. -

**PHP Code :**

```
   while($npacket>=1) {
       $count=0;
       $out_file=fopen("packet.txt","w");

       while($count<$payload_length ) {
           $c=fgetc($file);
           fputs($out_file,$c);
           $count++;
       }

       $data_file=`cat packet.txt`;

       if($datatyp=="ascii")
           $fpayload="-f packet.txt";
       else if($datatyp=="hex")
           $fpayload="-d0x$data_file";


       $random="";

       if( $ip=="tcp" || $ip=="udp" ) 
            exec("sendip -v -p ipv6 $fpayload  $random $adv_cont -6s $sip $optext -p  $proto $cont -$s $sapp_port -$d $dapp_port $dip ");

       else {
```

**Problem is Here ....**

```
       echo "this is $fpayload it";

       exec(" echo sendip -v -p ipv6 $fpayload $random $adv_cont -6s $sip $optext -p icmp $icmp_cont $dip > sample ");

       }

       usleep("$igap");

       if(!$flag)
           $npacket--;

       }

       fclose($out_file);
       fclose($file);

       }
```

For 1 packet and payload specified as a input,

1) Input : 616263646566

[image]

Output :

```
  $ cat payload.txt 
  616263646566
  $ cat packet.txt 
  616263646566
  $ cat sample 
  $
```

2) Input : 6162636465666768

Output :

```
  $ cat payload.txt 
  6162636465666768
  $ cat packet.txt 
  6162636465666768
  $ cat sample 
  sendip -v -p ipv6 -d0x6162636465666768   -6s 2001::100  -p icmp  2001::200
```

Please help me find out where does exactly problem lies ?

**EDIT:**

Permission of files :

```
 $ ls -l payload.txt packet.txt sample 
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 udit udit 13 Nov 17 20:57 packet.txt
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 udit udit 13 Nov 17 20:57 payload.txt
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 udit udit  0 Nov 17 20:57 sample
```

Comment: strange even after more than 24 hours not even a single response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was actually presence of whitespaces and null characters at the end of **$fpayload** variable. Just needed to add one regular expression syntax in else part.

```
.........
else if($datatyp=="hex") {
     $fpayload="-d0x$data_file";
     $fpayload=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $fpayload);

}
....
```